# Where should I implement this Jackson Root Element code within my HTTPClass?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, jackson

I am attempting to implement Jackson library to parse Json for the first time. Where should I implement this Jackson Root Element code within my HTTPClass? Also what other changes do I need to make to my HTTPClass?

**Jackson code for retrieving Json from server**

```
RootElement rootElement = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);
    // this line is very important
    objectMapper.configure(

DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

try {
        rootElement = objectMapper.readValue(result, RootElement.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**HTTPClass**

```
 ...
public static void getDailyStorylineList(final MovesHandler<ArrayList<StorylineData>> handler,
                                                 final String specificSummary,
                                                 final String from,
                                                 final String to,
                                                 final String pastDays,
                                                 final String updatedSince,
                                                 final boolean needTrackPoints) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        /* Refresh access token if only AuthData.MOVES_REFRESHBEFORE days are there to expire current token */
                        AuthData.refreshAccessTokenIfNeeded();

                    /* Exchange the authorization code we obtained after login to get access token */
                    HashMap<String, String> nameValuePairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    nameValuePairs.put("access_token", AuthData.getAuthData().getAccessToken());

                   // if (specificSummary != null && specificSummary.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("specificSummary", specificSummary);//att

                    if (from != null && from.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("from", from);
                    if (to != null && to.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("to", to);
                    if (pastDays != null && pastDays.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("pastDays", pastDays);
                    if (updatedSince != null && updatedSince.length() > 0) nameValuePairs.put("updatedSince", updatedSince);
                    if (needTrackPoints) nameValuePairs.put("trackPoints", "true");


                    URL url     = new URL(MovesAPI.API_BASE + MovesAPI.API_PATH_STORYLINE + (specificSummary != null ? specificSummary : "") + "?" + Utilities.encodeUrl(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                        /* All other HTTP errors from Moves will fall here */
                        handler.onFailure(getErrorStatus(Utilities.readStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream()), urlConnection.getResponseCode()), "Server not responded with success ("+ urlConnection.getResponseCode() +")");
                        return;
                    }

                    String response = Utilities.readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    Object object = new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                    if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object;
                        ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData = new ArrayList<StorylineData>();
                        if (jsonArray != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject storylineJsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                                if (storylineJsonObject != null) {
                                    storylineData.add(StorylineData.parse(storylineJsonObject));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        handler.onSuccess(storylineData);
                    } else {
                        handler.onFailure(MovesStatus.INVALID_RESPONSE, "Expected a JSONArray from server, but failed");
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    handler.onFailure(MovesStatus.UNEXPECTED_ERROR, "An unexpected error occured, please check logcat");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

after check on the http RC value

before your code useing the String response

you can just use the jackson API on http.response.inputStream

```
byte[] response = new ByteArrayInputStream(httpResponse.getInputStream())

try {
    JsonNode _node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(response), JsonNode.class);
// ref elements within RootObj that r needed                        
    String itmId =  node.path("objectId").getTextValue();
    }
```